# How to get two decimals from division in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using:

```
SELECT 2/3
```

How can I get the result `0.67` using SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT ROUND(2.0/3.0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select cast(2.0/3.0 as decimal(3,2)) as result`, should help.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select cast(ROUND(2/3.0, 2) as decimal(2,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetDecimalFromDivided(@interger1 INT, @interger2 INT , @round INT) 
RETURNS FLOAT AS
Begin
RETURN  ROUND(@interger1/cast(cast(@interger2 AS VARCHAR) + '.0' AS FLOAT),@round)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 2.0/3.0 AS RawResult
```

Format in client

Comments on the function in your answer...

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetDecimalFromDivided (@float1 float, @float2 float, @round INT) 
RETURNS float AS
Begin
RETURN ROUND (@float/@float2, @round)
END
```

- Why send integer in?
- round is meaningless with a return type of float. You may get 0.6700000000001 for example
- If you want to fix decimal places, use decimal(p,2). But then your ROUND is useless.

You really should **format in the client!**